# DataAnnotations not getting reflected when using on MetaData class present in different project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning Asp.Net MVC. I stumbled on such a thing while practising. I have Shop Project consisting of the simple `Shopie` Data Model which is a partial class. I applied DataAnnotations on another partial class `ShopElob` which is a MetaData class for this Shop Data Model.

```
namespace Shop
{
  public partial class Shopie
  {
  public int ShopieId { get; set; }
  public String ShopieName { get; set; }
  public string Landmark { get; set; }
  public decimal Minprice { get; set; }
  public String Email { get; set; }
  }
}
```

ShopElob

```
namespace Shop
{
[MetadataType(typeof(ShopElob))]
public partial class Shop
{
}

public class ShopElob
{
[Display(Name = "Shopiez Name")]
public String ShopName { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
public decimal MinPrice { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public String Email { get; set; }
}
}
```

But when I create Strongly typed view of `Shopie` Model in another MVC project `DataAnnotationsdemo`, the UI doesn't reflect the DataAnnotations from the MetaData class even after referecing the Shop project in MVC project and provided the following code in Web.config of Views

```
<Pages>
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="Shop.Shopie"/>
  </namespaces>
</Pages>
```

In controller I have the following code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 PopulateData pd = new PopulateData();
 Shopie s=pd.beginPopulate();
 return View(s);
 }
```

And in View I specified the model as

```
@model Shop.Shopie
```

The above two projects lie within one solution.

Answer (score 0):

So for me the approach here isn't correct - I think its good practice to have your entity framework in a separate project but I would still create an annotated ViewModel class in the Presentation layer. The reason for this is that it moves more towards a solution that conforms to separation of concerns and ensures all information related to presentation is in the presentation layer with data and logic in a separate DAL project.

I would create a static class called EntityViewModelExtensions in the presentation layer that looks something like this.

```
public static ShopViewModel ToViewModel(this Shop model)
{
    return new ShopViewModel
    {
        ShopName = model.ShopName,
        MinPrice = model.MinPrice,
        Email = model.Email
    };
}
```

This can be called within your Controller Action as

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     PopulateData pd = new PopulateData();
     ShopViewModel s = pd.beginPopulate().Select(p => p.ToViewModel()).ToList();
     return View(s);
 }
```

Your ShopViewModel would then look like

```
public class ShopViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Shopiez Name")]
    public String ShopName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
    public decimal MinPrice { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public String Email { get; set; }
 }
```

The page itself would accept a model of type ShopViewModel.

This then means all information relating to presentation (including Model Annotations and Display Attributes) are kept within the presentation layer whereas all information related to Database and Business Logic is in the DAL.

I gave a talk on this topic a few weeks ago at DotNetNotts, if you want to check it out you can see it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mt61XGZv0jI).

In the interests of completeness, if you did want to continue with your existing approach I think the reason it is failing is related to the name space. The name space you should be referencing is Shop. I've tested this on a very similar project and its worked without any issues with your code effectively copied and pasted as is.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for SOC tip and your video is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

The point which was blocking Data Annotations to be applied in View was that the `MetaData` attribute was not applied on exact class.

Before:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ShopElob))]
public partial class Shop
{
}
```

Correct Form is:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ShopElob))]
public partial class Shopie
{
}
```

And the rest works fine. Obviously I prefer to opt Soc concepts suggested by @Steve Westgarth